# How do I import data with different types from file into a Python Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a file `myfile.txt` containing:

```
1   2.0000  buckle_my_shoe
3   4.0000  margery_door
```

**How do I import data from the file to a numpy array as an int, float and string?**

I am aiming to get:

```
array([[1,2.0000,"buckle_my_shoe"],
[3,4.0000,"margery_door"]])
```

I've been playing around with the following to no avail:

```
a = numpy.loadtxt('myfile.txt',dtype=(numpy.int_,numpy.float_,numpy.string_))
```

EDIT: Another approach might be to use the ndarray type and convert afterwards.

```
b = numpy.loadtxt('myfile.txt',dtype=numpy.ndarray)

    array([['1', '2.0000', 'buckle_my_shoe'],
       ['3', '4.0000', 'margery_door']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Just read the file to a string, split the string on each `\n` newline and explode those inners with the 3- and 2 spaces. Otherwise you can also just use Regular Expressions to find each lines and split them up (groups).

Comment: I think the more important question is what you're going to do with this data after it's imported.  While you can use `numpy` to work with non-numerical data, if you want to do anything fun with it you're probably going to wind up reinventing bits of `pandas`..

Comment: For more basic explanations you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10940038/2062965

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.genfromtxt('filename', dtype= None)
# array([(1, 2.0, 'buckle_my_shoe'), (3, 4.0, 'margery_door')], 
#       dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '|S14')])
```

Answer (score 7):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) can do that for you. The docs for the function you could use are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html).

Assuming your columns are tab separated, this should do the trick (adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652832/python-pandas-how-do-i-load-a-tsv-file-into-a-pandas-dataframe)):

```
df = DataFrame.from_csv('myfile.txt', sep='\t')
array = df.values # the array you are interested in
```