# Extract numbers and text from csv file with Python3.X

Tags: python-3.x, csv, numpy, genfromtxt

I am trying to extract data from a csv file with python 3.6.
The data are both numbers and text (it's url addresses):

```
 file_name = [-0.47,  39.63, http://example.com]
```

On multiple forums I found this kind of code:

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', skip_header=skiplines,)
```

But this works for numbers only, the url addresses are read as NaN.

If I add dtype:

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', skip_header=skiplines, dtype=None)
```

The url addresses are read correctly, but they got a "b" at the beginning of the address, such as:

```
 b'http://example.com'
```

How can I remove that? How can I just have the simple string of text?

I also found this option:

```
file = open(file_path, "r")
csvReader = csv.reader(file)
for row in csvReader:
    variable = row[i]
    coordList.append(variable)
```

but it seems it has some issues with python3.

Comment: The answers on this one show a pure Python and a Numpy solution using genfromtext for mixed data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277183/python-numpy-read-a-text-file-with-mixed-format

Comment: "but it seems it has some issues with python3.": which are? Don't leave us guessing, show the problems. (Likely, just as the prepended `b`, you're running into unicode issues with Python 3.

Comment: You can convert a bytes object `b'http://example.com'` to a `str` by using the `.decode()` method: `b'http://example.com'.decode()`, for example. The reason `getfromtxt` is reading a bytes object, is that it has *no* idea what kind of text it is (boring English, or Chinese, or ...?), hence it assumes it's just a bunch of bytes. It's up to you to convert it. Alternatively, you could try and specify the dtype in `genfromtxt`, use e.g. `'U80'` and things may work better. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001373/loading-utf-8-file-in-python-3-using-numpy-genfromtxt).

Comment: The `b` just means `genfromtxt` has loaded the string as a bytestring.  The default string type in Py3 is `unicode`.  In  Py2 bytestring is the default.

Comment: Look at the `data.dtype`.  The text field will have an `Sn` type.  If it was unicode it would have `Un`.  It's possible to specify a `dtype` (rather than the authomatic `None`) with a `U` type if the `b` really bothers you.  For many uses it doesn't matter whether the string is unicode or byte.

Comment: Thanks Evert, I got it!