# How to convert a .csv file into a numpy array of different type

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, scikit-learn

So I have a little problem. I have a .csv matrix that I want to transform in a numpy array  so i found this:
np.genfromtxt('/Users/username/Documents/fichieretudebis.csv', delimiter= ';')

The matter is that my .csv matrix contains number and string, and I need both of them to appear in my array ( but I want them to keep their type)
I tried to transform the matrix in a str matrix (with dtype=str) but I can't transform the number back in a float type.
Does someone know how to do it ?
Thx

More explanation :

My .csv file is like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brNeb.png)

I need to use this file in order to create a tree ( using sklearn and Random forest algorithms)

This is what I currently wrote
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvNBq.png)

( file called ResultatBis and Previsionbis have the same problem ).

I don't know how to create a array that's going to be recognize by sklearn without using the numpylibrary but I need my matrix to stay exactly the same.

Tell me if that's enough explanation and thx for your future help !

Comment: numpy is for homogeneous, aligned,  data.  for more exotic schemes, have a look  at pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
prediction = pd.read_csv('/Users/username/Documents/fichieretudebis.csv', delimiter= ';')
```

Pandas is very popular for reading and manipulating data from .csv datasets. In my machine learning assignments I've always used it.

Answer (score 2):

do

```
np.genfromtxt('/Users/username/Documents/fichieretudebis.csv', delimiter= ';',dtype=None)
```

(after https://stackoverflow.com/a/15481761/1461850)

Comment: Thx ! It's going to help me  but how do you get ride of  a b in front of all string elements.   [(44, 75007, 0, 0, 0, b'gmail') (31, 75018, 13, 1, 0, b'gmail')
 (25, 75001, 11, 1, 1, b'gmail') (11, 75019, 4, 1, 0, b'gmail')] This is the type of output I get

Comment: The `b` is just Python3's way of indicating that it read byte (ASCII) strings from your file.  Py3's default string type is `unicode`.  Look at the `dtype`.  For this field it probably is `<S5` or the like.  Under Python2 you wouldn't see the `b`, but the dtype would be the same.